# C# How to implement flag messaging system between two methods in a business logic class of a WCF app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have two methods in a C# business logic class. I need a flag mechanism so that one method can update the flag and the other method will react when the flag is updated. Below I will paste my situation, which is very simple:

```
// BusinessLogic.cs
bool photoResizingFinished = false;

public int SavePhoto() {

while (!photoResizingFinished)  {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        Trace.TraceInformation("PhotoResizingWorkerRole has not finnished yet.");
     } }

public bool UpdateStatus(bool statusUpdate) {
   photoResizingFinished = statusUpdate;
   return true; 
}
```

The two methods above live in the same class BusinessLogic.cs.

The only thing I need is to be able to have `SavePhoto()` react when
the `bool photoResizingFinished` is updated by `UpdateStatus(bool statusUpdate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have found a solution to my problem using a Multithreaded Singleton

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Here are some attempts of implementation:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1783765.aspx/2/10?How+to+have+two+methods+of+the+same+class+flag+to+eachother+

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/abd53523-658b-442a-bac0-1c74c1d90a90

I don't understand the mecanics of this myself totally, but I hope it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class as a webservice and implement callback function that called when the ws finishes its work.
example code:

```
    <script>
      var timerID = setTimeout(CallWS, 1000)//call a js func which calls the WevService

      function CallWS()
        {
           clearTimeout(timerID)//to stop the calling...
           WSClassName.WSFuncName(param1,param2,....,callBackSuccess,callBackFailur)
          ///the param1,param2 are according to the parameter the function is expected to get.
        }

     function callBackSuccess(result,eventArgs)
     {
         //When the WS function finished successfuly 
        //**set flag to true.**
     }
     function callBackFailur(result,eventArgs)
     {
       //when error occured in the WS function
        alert(result.get_message()).
     }

    </script>
```

Let me know if you need more help...
goodluck!

Comment: Do you have any tutorial or code example for this? (I am just a beginner)

Comment: I changed my answer and added some example code. see if it helps you and let me know.

Comment: thank you, but my business logic is only C#, I have uploaded a .txt file which explains my situation clearly: < https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5c0bc0a6f7bdc3c6#cid=5C0BC0A6F7BDC3C6&id=5C0BC0A6F7BDC3C6%21164 >

Comment: why you don't simple ask in the function 'UpdateStatus' if(statusUpdate==true) then call SavePhoto().

Comment: Because "SavePhoto()" sends the photos off to be resized in an Azure worker role. The statement "while (!photoResizingFinished)" is located inside SavePhoto(). "photoResizingFinished" is updated by the worker role when it has finnished the resizing of the photos. Anyway I have realized that this subject is a little too complex for me, so I will leave it as is. Thank you for the response, and sorry for the confusion. [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/abd53523-658b-442a-bac0-1c74c1d90a90)

Comment: you don't have to be sorry, I'm happy to help when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Task class from .Net 4.  It allows you to queue up tasks, so your SavePhoto() code would wait until the PhotoResizing() method finished.

Here's a nice article on the Task namespace if you want more details: http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public void SavePhoto(CancellationTokenSource taskCancellationTokenSource){

   // preliminary code

   // start resize
   Task resizeTask =  Task.Factory.StartNew( ResizePhoto, taskCancellationTokenSource ) ;

   // queue up final save method
   Task finalTask = resizeTask.ContinueWith(t => {
     if (!t.IsFaulted && !t.IsCancelled){
         FinishSaving();
     }
   });

   // Wait for everything to finish
   finalTask.Wait(taskCancellationTokenSource);
}

public void ResizePhoto(){
  // code
}

public void FinishSaving(){
   // code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mike Parkhill, but does it really have to be so complex? All I want is actually just to share a variable between two methods of the same class. I could do it if I made the variable static, but that's not a good idea, because there are more users. Doesn't C# have some language construct which allows me to do the task described in the initial post nice and easy? Anyway thank you for your response, I will chew on it.

Comment: How are the methods running - are they running in the same instance, or are you expecting them to be on separate instances?

How are you handling the threading?  Are you controlling the threads or is someone else?

Comment: Well it's just a WCF Azure web role I am implementing in Visual Studio, my code was working in VS when I just used a static variable as flag, but then I thought that maybe it was a bad idea, because multiple clients can access the service and I would not want multiple clients to share the same static variable. I am just a little student only implementing things in VS. So I was looking for something a little better than using a static variable to communicate in between two methods of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the bool like this:

```
bool _photoResizingFinished=false;
bool photoResizingFinished
{
    get{return _photoResizingFinished;}
    set
    {
     if(value) SavePhoto();            
     _photoResizingFinished=value;
    }
}
```

Or, you can make UpdatePhoto() call SavePhoto() after updating the bool. Might be a better solution.